# Get the value of a variable using the hexadecimal memory address

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I just want to get the value using the hex address:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int *hold, value=10;
   hold = &value;
   printf("%p",hold);
}
```

It gives me the address `0x7fffd7c24334`. I just want to know that if there is a way in C or C++ so that I can get directly the value of "value" using hex number `0x7fffd7c24334` for the time being. I suppose the address of the variable `hold` is the same for sometime so that `0x7fffd7c24334` still point to `value`, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that this address is consistent upon every execution of your program, you can use this:

```
int value2 = *(int*)0x7fffd7c24334;
```

But please note that this assumption is generally wrong!

The address of a local variable in a function depends on the state of the stack (the value of the SP register) at the point in execution when the function is called.

It might possibly work in `main`, since this function is called only once, and the SP register should have the same value upon every execution of your program. But even if it does work, that address will change as soon as you add variables before `value`. To put it in simple words, **don't** use this method.

Comment: Can you tell `int value2 = *(0x7fffd7c24334)` is right or not?

Comment: @BlackMamba that won't compile because you can't dereference an integer.  You'd need to cast the integer to a pointer first, *then* dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%d",*hold);
```

De-reference and use `%d`.

You cannot rely on the hex address.

See here: http://ideone.com/RdY4Ni

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this:

```
printf("%x", hold);
```